# How to access SQLite database in Tomcat using JDBC? UnsatisfiedLinkError thrown

Tags: java, sqlite, tomcat, jdbc

I'm developing web Java application with Servlet, JSP, JSTL technologies. I use SQLite3 database, develop in IntelliJ Idea IDE, compile project with Maven and test in Tomcat 9.0.

I can access SQLite database directly (using command line and sqlite3 downloaded library: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBS9S.png)).

I also can access SQLite database via JDBC as a plain JavaSE application when I run it in intellij idea: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7iN1.png).

But when I start my web project on Tomcat, on the web page ServletException is thrown cased by UnsatisfiedLinkError:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message Servlet execution threw an exception

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._open_utf8(byte[], int)'
    org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._open_utf8(Native Method)
    org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._open(NativeDB.java:71)
    org.sqlite.core.DB.open(DB.java:174)
    org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.open(CoreConnection.java:220)
    org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.<init>(CoreConnection.java:76)
    org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.<init>(JDBC3Connection.java:25)
    org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:24)
    org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:45)
    org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:114)
    org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:88)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:53)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:355)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:116)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:605)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:809)
    model.DAO.getRooms(DAO.java:29)
    servlets.HomepageServlet.doGet(HomepageServlet.java:55)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

In a tomcat's startup.bat command line window I see this:

```
06-Sep-2020 21:11:37.875 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-32] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/testProject_war_exploded] has started
06-Sep-2020 21:11:38.352 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-32] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
06-Sep-2020 21:11:38.375 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-32] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/testProject_war_exploded] is completed
C:\Dropbox\apache-tomcat-9.0.22\temp\sqlite-3.21.0.1-02fa308c-7c4d-4cfb-93cb-3e46dbaa56a1-sqlitejdbc.dll.lck (Системе не удается найти указанный путь)
```

(System cannot find the path specified)

This is the method which throws an exception:

```
package model;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DAO {
    private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
    private final String driverName = "org.sqlite.JDBC";

    public List<Room> getRooms() {
        List<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<Room>();
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
            Context ctx = new InitialContext();
            DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/rooms");
            connection = ds.getConnection();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            log.debug("Can't get class. No driver found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.debug("Can't get connection. Incorrect URL");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            log.debug("Can't get Context or Datasource");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.debug("Some other exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM room";
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            Room room;
            while (rs.next()) {
                room = new Room();
                room.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                room.setCountryCode(rs.getString("country_code"));
                room.setLightOn(rs.getInt("light_status"));
                rooms.add(room);
                log.debug(room.getName() + " " + room.getCountryCode() + "" + room.isLightOn());
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.debug("SQL Exception thrown during select statement");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.debug("Can't close connection");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rooms;
    }
}
```

Precisely this row is written in Servlet's exception as : model.DAO.getRooms(DAO.java:28)

```
connection = ds.getConnection();
```

However this code I used for SQLite access check without Tomcat works fine.
So it makes me think it's completely on "tomcat side"

```
import model.Room;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
    private final String driverName = "org.sqlite.JDBC";
    private final String connectionString = "jdbc:sqlite:rooms.db";

    public void run() {
        List<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<Room>();
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            log.debug("Can't get class. No driver found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.debug("Can't get connection. Incorrect URL");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM room";
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            Room room;
            while (rs.next()) {
                room = new Room();
                room.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                room.setCountryCode(rs.getString("country_code"));
                room.setLightOn(rs.getInt("light_status"));
                rooms.add(room);
                System.out.println(room.getName() + " " + room.getCountryCode() + " " + room.isLightOn());
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.debug("SQL Exception thrown during select statement");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.debug("Can't close connection");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main app = new Main();
        app.run();
    }
}
```

In order for Tomcat to find my database I created resource-ref in web.xml

```
    <resource-ref>
        <description>Rooms Database</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/rooms</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
```

And also added Context tag into tomcat-dir\conf\Catalina\localhost\testProject_war_exploded.xml
where testProject_war_exploded is the name of my app.

```
<Context reloadable="true" antiJARLocking="true" path="/" docBase="C:\Users\nativ\IdeaProjects\testProject\out\artifacts\testProject_war_exploded\">
    <Resource name="jdbc/rooms"
      auth="Container"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      driverClassName="org.sqlite.JDBC"
      url="jdbc:sqlite:rooms.db">
    </Resource>
</Context>
```

I also tried instead creating context.xml with the same Context tag into /META-INF/context.xml with the same code.

Or I tried adding Context tag into GlobalNamingResources tag in tomcat-dir/conf/server.xml - which is not recommended, I know, but still no result.

I am sure tomcat finds that rooms.db file because if I change path - I get SQLException and a "Can't get connection. Incorrect URL" written into my log file.

I am sure tomcat load sqlite3 jar library because we have exception thrown from org.sqlite.core package.

Although I am confused why I have no record in my log file from this getRooms() method if I catch any Exception. But if I catch (Throwable), then I have a log file record - that means an Error is thrown.

In SQLite documentation I found [a variable](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_temp_store) to tell sqlite whether to use temp folder or memory.
I can change it [via command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiZWH.png), but Tomcat uses sqlite3 jar library to open my database.
Should I change something in that jar? I have no idea why sqlite3 in tomcat tries to access this /temp/... folder.

[This is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xQAi.png) my web project structure which idea creates in \out directory.

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>testProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.6.2</junit.jupiter.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- API for countries' names and codes list -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.neovisionaries</groupId>
            <artifactId>nv-i18n</artifactId>
            <version>1.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.maxmind.geoip2</groupId>
            <artifactId>geoip2</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.21.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>exe</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And Servlet class that handles index page.

```
package servlets;

import com.maxmind.geoip2.record.Country;
import com.neovisionaries.i18n.CountryCode;

import controller.LocationHelper;
import model.DAO;
import model.Room;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;


import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class HomepageServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private LocationHelper locationHelper = new LocationHelper();
    private DAO dao = new DAO();
    private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String roomName = request.getParameter("roomName");
        log.debug("roomName = " + roomName);

        String selectedCountry = request.getParameter("countryList");
        log.debug("selectedCountry = " + selectedCountry);

        doGet(request, response);
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");

        String ipStr = LocationHelper.getClientIpAddr(request);
        request.setAttribute("ipAddress", ipStr);

        String countryStr = "not determined";
        String countrycode = "no code";
        Country country = locationHelper.getCountry(getServletContext());
        if (country != null) {
            countryStr = country.getName();
            countrycode = country.getIsoCode();
        }

        request.setAttribute("country", countryStr);
        request.setAttribute("code", countrycode);

        List<String> countries = getSortedCountriesList();
        request.setAttribute("countriesList", countries);

        List<Room> rooms = dao.getRooms();
        request.setAttribute("roomsList", rooms);

        requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return Sorted countries list to be shown in a dropdown list.
     */
    private List<String> getSortedCountriesList() {
        List<String> countriesList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (CountryCode code : CountryCode.values()) {
            countriesList.add(code.getName());
        }

        Collections.sort(countriesList, (s1, s2) -> s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2));
        return countriesList;
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens when you replace `connection = ds.getConnection();` with `connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:rooms.db");`? It should work provided the `WEB-INF/lib` has the driver jar.

Comment: The jar was in WEB-INF/lib folder and still it gives me the same exception. I also put sqilte jar directly into tomcat/lib folder, but still the same message about not found \temp\... folder

Answer (score 0):

More likely you are missing the native libraries, which are required by `sqlite-jdbc`.

https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sqlite/SQLiteJDBCLoader.java#L305

Try to provide `org.sqlite.lib.path` property to jvm pointing to location of sqlite shared libraries.

Comment: I put sqlite jar directly into tomcat/lib folder and before database access code wrote set property like this: `System.setProperty("org.sqlite.lib.path", "${catalina.home}" + "/lib/sqlite-jdbc-3.21.0.1.jar");` But when I decided to look first what this property was, getProperty() gave me exactly that string I was setting up. Servlet still throws the same error, but startup cmd gives no "not found /temp/... dir". Instead it writes failed to unregistrate JDBC driver [link](http://ssmaker.ru/af0bc09c.png) Does that mean JDBC driver is registered, but not unregistered because of the error thrown?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite will create a DB file when the connection is created at the IDE root folder, To handle this and point to your targeted DB, Just use its full path, Here are the steps:

1. Put the sqlite-jdbc jar file in **Tomcat\lib** folder
2. Put your database file [MyDB.db OR MyDB.sqlite] in **Tomcat\lib** folder or create another folder "db" and point to it using its full path while creating the **Connection** object.